# Saving custom data for each user

Tags: custom-field

I allow users to save some notes on my wordpress site. They can only do this after they login to the site.

Now I want to save their notes in a database table and associate them with the user's id i.e. if a user has saved 2 notes, when they login and go to "my page", they should be able to see the 2 notes they saved.

Can someone please guide me on how to do this? I could find a lot of information on saving custom user metadata when they register. But could not find any help on saving information associated with a user account after they have logged in.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [update_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)
you can save user data if they are registering or signed in, its just a matter of what user ID you pass to it.

say in your function to save the user data after he is logged in:

```
function save_user_data_7231(){
    global $current_user;
    if is_user_logged_in{ //check if user is logged in.
        if (isset($_POST['Notes'])){
            // get current user info
            get_currentuserinfo();
            $old_notes = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'user_notes', true);
            if (isset($old_notes)&& is_array($old_notes)){
                //if we saved already more the one notes
                $old_notes[] = $_POST['Notes'];
                update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'user_notes', $old_notes);
            }
            if (isset($old_notes)&& !is_array($old_notes)){
                //if we saved only one note before
                $new_notes = array($old_notes,$_POST['Notes']);
                update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'user_notes', $new_notes)
            }
            if (!isset($old_notes)){
                //first note we are saving fr this user
                update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'user_notes', $_POST['Notes'])
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

they to display there notes you can use [get_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)

```
function get_user_notes_654(){
    global $current_user;
    if is_user_logged_in{ //check if user is logged in.
        // get current user info
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $old_notes = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'user_notes', true);
        if (!isset($old_notes)){
            $re = 'No Notes YET!';
        }
        if (isset($old_notes)){//we have notes. Removed the extra ! here.
            if (is_array($old_notes)){//more then one
                foreach($old_notes as $note){
                    $re .= '<strong>note:</strong>' . $note . '<br />'; 
                }
            }else{//just one
                $re = '<strong>note:</strong>' . $old_notes . '<br />';
            }
        }
        re .='//add note form  would come here';
        return $re;
    }
}
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: thanks. what if I want to save data other than string - files for instance?

Comment: saving files would be processing the upload and saving the attachment id which can be saved as a string , also if you just save the url to the file after the upload its still a string.

Comment: @Bainternet i know this thread is old but i helps me. Just one question i haven't set a note and still `$old_notes = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'user_notes', true);
            echo 'old notes ' . isset($old_notes);` returns a 1 this should be 0/false, right?

Comment: Ok i edit your code a bit `if (!isset($old_notes[0])) {` seems to work like i expected. $old_notes always have an array as value?